# Parametrization of Unitary matrices

Tags: resource-recommendations, linear-algebra, quarks, unitarity

Is there any book to follow along with "[The Unitary and Rotation Groups" by F.D. Murnaghan](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwivwIKPsd35AhUw0HMBHQBJC8MQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.worldcat.org%2Ftitle%2Funitary-and-rotation-groups%2Foclc%2F490554568&usg=AOvVaw2EzBvE9iZ0gM9L4l-5_Qqf)" for the first two chapters concerning the parametrization of general $n \times n$ unitary matrices?